# rosmake failed : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'timeout'

Tags: rosmake, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do'nt know what I changed but since a short time rosmake doesn't want to work anymore.
Note that I am using a Dedian squeeze 6.0.1 2.6.35.7 64b with Electric (so it may be an electric issue, but I really don't think it is).

here is the complete log :

> ard@ard-host:/media/data/ros_electric/ard$
> rosmake arp_master [ rosmake ]
> Packages requested are: ['arp_master']
> [ rosmake ] Logging to
> directory/opt/ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110728-225747
> [ rosmake ] Expanded args
> ['arp_master'] to: ['arp_master']
> [ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps
> compliance for packages arp_master.
> This may take a few seconds.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/media/data/ros_electric/ros/bin/rosmake",
> line 63, in 
> if rma.main():   File "/media/data/ros_electric/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/rosmake.py",
> line 857, in main
> self.rosdep_check_result = self.check_rosdep(buildable_packages)
> File
> "/media/data/ros_electric/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/rosmake.py",
> line 288, in check_rosdep
> failed_rosdeps = r.check()   File "/media/data/ros_electric/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/core.py",
> line 463, in check
> if not self.install_rosdep(r, rdlp, default_yes=False,
> execute=False, display=display):
> File
> "/media/data/ros_electric/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/core.py",
> line 539, in install_rosdep
> my_installer = installer(rosdep_dict[mode])   File
> "/media/data/ros_electric/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/installers.py",
> line 133, in **init**
> contents = fetch_file(self.alt_url, self.md5sum)
> File
> "/media/data/ros_electric/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/installers.py",
> line 80, in fetch_file
> fh= urllib2.urlopen(url)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line
> 126, in urlopen
> return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File
> "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line
> 382, in open
> req.timeout = timeout AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has
> no attribute 'timeout' Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "/media/data/ros_electric/ros/bin/rosmake",
> line 63, in 
> if rma.main():   File "/media/data/ros_electric/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/rosmake.py",
> line 857, in main
> self.rosdep_check_result = self.check_rosdep(buildable_packages)
> File
> "/media/data/ros_electric/ros/tools/rosmake/src/rosmake/rosmake.py",
> line 288, in check_rosdep
> failed_rosdeps = r.check()   File "/media/data/ros_electric/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/core.py",
> line 463, in check
> if not self.install_rosdep(r, rdlp, default_yes=False,
> execute=False, display=display):
> File
> "/media/data/ros_electric/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/core.py",
> line 539, in install_rosdep
> my_installer = installer(rosdep_dict[mode])   File
> "/media/data/ros_electric/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/installers.py",
> line 133, in **init**
> contents = fetch_file(self.alt_url, self.md5sum)
> File
> "/media/data/ros_electric/ros/tools/rosdep/src/rosdep/installers.py",
> line 80, in fetch_file
> fh= urllib2.urlopen(url)   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line
> 126, in urlopen
> return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File
> "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line
> 382, in open
> req.timeout = timeout AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has
> no attribute 'timeout'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10761/rosmake-failed-:-attributeerror:-%27nonetype%27-object-has-no-attribute-%27timeout%27/) by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 352 on 2011-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hmmm, this is going in a pain way :( What is surprising is that is used to work. I did something like editing a manifest and rebuild. I may have problem with locales again (fr).

Did python switched to from 2.5 to 2.6 ? (I can't find the ros wiki page with the listed versions of core dependencies of ROS distribs).

None for a timeout here, afaik, is a special value that would set the socket in blocking mode. Is it done on purpose ?

---

Originally posted by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) with karma: 352 on 2011-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on 2011-07-28**:
It suddenly switched back into a working state, and I didn't do anything  on purpose that could explain that.